# jQuery toggleClass with conditionals/default states

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

Scenario: I have two buttons. In between the two buttons is a chevron image with three states defined with css. Each state has a class neutral, sell-it, buy-it. Depending on the page, the chevron could be in any one of the three states. On mouseover of either of the two buttons I'm trying to toggle the respective class. Example: If default state is class "buy-it" mousing over the buy it button will do nothing mousing over the sell it button will toggle the class "sell-it" but return to the default "buy-it" buy it on mouseout. If the chevron is in the neutral state mousing over either button would toggle buy-it/sell-it but return to neutral.

It's so close but not quite doing what I want.

```
    (function(){

  var buttonChevrons = (function(){

    var initialize = function(){
      _setDefault();
      _setListeners();
    }

    //set default state
    var _setDefault = function(){
      //$(".chevron").addClass("neutral");
    }
    //set event listeners
    var _setListeners = function(){
      //Buy button
      $("#btnbuy").hover(function(){
        //default neutral state
        if( $(".chevron").hasClass("neutral")) {
          $(".chevron").toggleClass("buy-it");
        }
        //if buy it
        else if( $(".chevron").hasClass("buy-it")) {
          $(".chevron").toggleClass("");
        }
        //if sell it
        else if( $(".chevron").hasClass("sell-it")) {
          $(".chevron").toggleClass("buy-it");
        }
      })
      //Sell button
      $("#btnsell").hover(function(){
        //default neutral state
        if( $(".chevron").hasClass("neutral")) {
          $(".chevron").toggleClass("sell-it");
        }
        //if sell it
        else if( $(".chevron").hasClass("sell-it")) {
          $(".chevron").toggleClass("");
        }
        //if buy it
        else { $(".chevron").hasClass("buy-it") 
          $(".chevron").toggleClass("sell-it");
        }
      })

    }

    //call initialize
    return {init: initialize}
  }());

    //call buttonChevrons
  this.buttonChevrons = buttonChevrons;
}).call(this);

$(document).ready(function(){

  buttonChevrons.init()

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because I can't leave well enough alone, I did this again using a lambda function to generate the callback functions for the `hover()` methods.  It doesn't save any lines of code in this case, but as a general technique it can be useful.  On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slashingweapon/8tr3n/)...

```
(function() {
    var chevron = $("#chevron");
    var defaultState;

    function toggle(tempClass, state) {
        return function(evt) {
            if (state) { chevron.toggleClass(defaultState, false); }
            chevron.toggleClass(tempClass, state);
            if (!state) { chevron.toggleClass(defaultState, true); }
        };
    }

    // decide on default state
    $.each(['buy-it', 'sell-it', 'neutral'], function(idx, initialClass) {
        if (chevron.hasClass(initialClass)) {
            defaultState = initialClass;
            return false;
        }
    });

    $("#btnbuy").hover(toggle('buy-it', true), toggle('buy-it', false));
    $("#btnsell").hover(toggle('sell-it', true), toggle('sell-it', false));
})();​
```

I'm not compulsive ... honest!  There's just nothing good on television tonight.

Comment: This is looking more promising, I like this logic. However, the default state is going to be specified in the markup and it could be different on each page. I just plugged this in and it works, kinda, about as good as what I already had...Hmm?

Comment: You can set the default state to buy-it, sell-it, or neutral and the rollovers work correctly.  The chevron state always returns to the default when you roll away.  Getting the default state is trivial ... just use `hasClass()` to test for which class is present already.

Comment: There.  I added initial state discovery and updated the fiddle.  Enjoy.